# I can not configure MySQL to run from terminal with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

I installed MAMP successfully and it works just fine, apache, phpMyAdmin, etc...and followed a tutorial video on youtube on how to configure MySQL so I can use it with terminal.  In short, I created a

```
.profile
```

file in my home directory with this data in it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export PATH
```

When I shut everything down and restarted the server and terminal and typed mysql in terminal, this is what I get:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Does anybody have any idea what my problem might be?  I'm using MAMP 2.0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know where it *is* located?

Comment: I thought it should be located in this path, when I went there, I did see mysql files there.  I thought someone here might know.  I just did a standard MAMP installation and then did the above.  I didn't move anything or edit anything.  Would it move itself somewhere else?  mysql seems to be working and running, the lightfor MySQL server is green in MAMP as is Apache.

Comment: I can just double click the MySQL file that's in that directory and it opens up in terminal and...I dunno...I guess I'm using MySQL.  I have no idea why the system can't find this file when this is the actual address.  It's very strange.